# Why Python `Memory Error` with list `append()` lots of RAM left

Tags: python, list, memory

I am building a large data dictionary from a set of text files.  As I read in the lines and process them, I `append(dataline)` to a list.

At some point the `append()` generates a `Memory Error` exception.  However, watching the program run in the Windows Task Manager, at the point of the crash I see 4.3 GB available and 1.1 GB free.

Thus, I do not understand the reason for the exception.

Python version is 2.6.6.  I guess, the only reason is that it is not able to use more of the available RAM.  If this is so, is it possible to increase the allocation?

Comment: Try using a 64-bit build of Python. Though if you are using any extension modules, they'll then need to be built 64-bit as well.

Comment: Can you print the `MemoryError` exception string? That should give us more info.

Comment: Are you appending before or after you process the lines?

Comment: @nmichaels- looks like this: `data.append(processraw(raw))`.  each `raw` is one line.

Comment: Show us more code and maybe we will be able to show you how to improve your memory consumption.  How big is your set of text files?  @aix is right about 32-bit versus 64-bit.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you're using a 32-bit build of Python, you might want to try a 64-bit version.

It is possible for a process to address at most 4GB of RAM using 32-bit addresses, but typically (depending on the OS), one gets much less. It sounds like your Python process may be hitting this limit. 64-bit addressing removes this limitation.

**edit** Since you're asking about Windows, the following page is of relevance: [Memory Limits for Windows Releases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366778(v=vs.85).aspx). As you can see, the limit per 32-bit process is 2, 3 or 4GB depending on the OS version and configuration.

Comment: Yes, 32-bit.  Any way to control how much is allocated?  Or to see how much is allocated?  I would like to verify if we are hitting the limit or not.  BTW the process is listed as using 1.9GB in the Task Manager window when it crashes.

Comment: @Pete You should be able to see this in the Task Manager: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/6/6b/System_idle_process.png (under "Mem Usage").

Comment: I meant to say, see what the allocation limit is or change it, in order to verify that we are out of memory, rather than assume 1.9GB, the current allocation, is the limit

Comment: @Pete Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366778(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Pete On that page I linked to, you want "User-mode virtual address space for each 32-bit process"

Comment: Yup, 2GB is the verified limit

Comment: Thanks, this saved me

Answer (score 5):

If you're open to restructuring the code instead of throwing more memory at it, you might be able to get by with this:

```
data = (processraw(raw) for raw in lines)
```

where `lines` is either a list of lines or `file.xreadlines()` or similar.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem using a 32-bit version of python in a 64-bit windows environment. I tried the 64-bit windows version of python and very quickly ran into troubles with the Scipy libraries compiled for 64-bit windows.

The totally free solution that I implemented was

1) Install VirtualBox
2) Install CentOS 5.6 on the VM
3) Get the Enthought Python Distribution (Free 64 bit Linux Version).

Now all of my Numpy, Scipy, and Matplotlib dependant python code can use as much memory as I have Ram and available Linux swap.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem happening when evaluating an expression containing large `numpy` arrays (actually, one was sparse). I was doing this on a machine with 64GB of memory, of which only about 8GB was in use, so was surprised to get the `MemoryError`.

It turned out that my problem was array shape broadcasting: I had inadvertently duplicated a large dimension.

It went something like this:

- I had passed an array with shape `(286577, 1)` where I was expecting `(286577)`.
- This was subracted from an array with shape `(286577, 130)`.
- Because I was expecting `(286577)`, I applied `[:,newaxis]` in the expression to bring it to `(286577,1)` so it would be broadcast to `(286577,130)`.
- When I passed shape `(286577,1)` however, `[:,newaxis]` produced shape `(286577,1,1)` and the two arrays were both broadcast to shape `(286577,286577,130)` ... of doubles. With two such arrays, that comes to about 80GB!

Answer (score 0):

As its been already mentioned, you'll need a python64 bit (of a 64-bit version of windows).

Be aware that you'll probably face a lot of conflicts and problems with some of the basic packages you might want to work with. to avoid this problem I'd recommend [Anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda) from Continuum Analytics. I'd advice you to look into it :)