# Python returning MemoryError with plenty of free ram available

Tags: python, memory, ram

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why Python `Memory Error` with list `append()` lots of RAM left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441947/why-python-memory-error-with-list-append-lots-of-ram-left)

I am working on a windows 7 - 64 bit machine with 6GB of ram. The python interpreter I am using is 2.6.5

My work involves signal processing of very large datasets (typically 50k - 200k samples per second with 1 to 16 parallel signals).

While working in python I get MemoryError thrown typically when the system Resource Monitor reports that python has a Commit (total memory reserved) of 1.1 to 1.3 GB. It doesn't seem to matter what I am doing to hit the 1.1 - 1.3 GB range; appending to lists, allocating numpy arrays, using fftconvolve. There is always plenty of more memory available so why can I not use more than ~1.1 GB ?

I can get around this by reading and writing to files to free ram, but to me it seems I am doing something wrong to be getting memory errors before I am actually out of memory.

Comment: Are you using a 64-bit build of Python?

Comment: Also, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441947/why-python-memory-error-with-list-append-lots-of-ram-left

Comment: No I am using a 32-bit build of python (specifically the pythonXY distribution). However even with only 32bit addresses I should be able to use up to just over 4GB.