# MemoryError while reading from a large file (~2.5GB) and storing into a python list

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io

I am trying to process lines in a really huge file using python.
I  found out the best ways to read a large file, from the many previously answered questions here in stackoverflow. I picked up one of the ways and checked it as in the following :

```
fIn = fopen(fileName,'rU')
fOut = fopen(fileName1, 'w')
while 1:
    lines = fIn.readlines(100000)
    if not lines:
        break
    for line in lines :
            fOut.write(line)
```

This worked like magic and I was able to successfully read lines from one file and write it to another and did not encounter any MemoryErrors.

But what I now want to do is instead of writing the lines read form one file into another file, I want to store them in a list and then do my further processing on the list. My code to store the lines in a list is shown below :

```
fIn = fopen(fileName,'rU')
fOut = fopen(fileName1, 'w')
d = []
while 1:
    lines = fIn.readlines(100000)
    if not lines:
        break
    for line in lines :
            d.append(line)
```

This code is creating MemoryError and the stack trace printed on the prompt shows that the last line executed before this error is the d.append(line) line. So definitely writing large amounts of data into a list is causing error. This error is caused a few seconds into the program. So it is able to write data upto a certain size properly and then finding some memory fault.

I wanted to know what is the best way to store huge files in lists within python and hence not encounter the MemoryError fault.

Comment: You've basically just re-created the problem your original code was intended to avoid, which was to prevent having more than 100000 entries in memory at the same time. If you're on a `32bit` python instance, what you want to do is impossible, you only have `~2GB` of RAM available to your process.

Comment: What kind of processing you are going to do? Does the processing depend on all the lines of text at once?

Comment: You might not have enough RAM, or could be not fully allocating it. Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441947/why-python-memory-error-with-list-append-lots-of-ram-left) for more info, especially if you are running Windows.

Comment: @thefourtheye : No the processing is independent of  all lines and can be done line by line too. But then I will have to rewrite the whole processing code that I spend a day writing and debugging for smaller sized files. I guess I was being lazy and trying to find a lazy solution.

Comment: @aruisdante : thanks for the answer. The python version I  use (version 2.7.6) is a 64-bit version. Is it still impossible with this version? I just check my system settings , I have 32GB RAM too!

Comment: @Louis , you are right, i did not have enough RAM. Thanks for the link , i checked the description there. I then checked my settings and saw that i have a 32-bit version of python, running on 64 bit windows on an x86 machine. According to [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366778(v=vs.85).aspx) this allows 2GB RAM. I watched the python process in my task manager and saw that when the program crashed the memory usage was about 1.8GB . So I guess the only solution for me is to do line by line processing. Thanks a lot

Comment: @aruisdante , you are right, what I want to do impossible because I just checked and found out that I have a 32-bit python though running on a 64 bit machine. So I am limited to 2GB RAM for the python process.  Thanks for helping me understand this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since [processing can be done line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22548446/memoryerror-while-reading-from-a-large-file-2-5gb-and-storing-into-a-python-l?noredirect=1#comment34318282_22548446), the best choice would be to iterate over the file object like this

```
with open(fileName, 'rU') as fIn:
    for line in fIn:
        process_line(line)
```

and move all the processing logic to the `process_line` function. This will be best choice because, it gets you only one line at the time. So, you are not clogging the memory.

Comment: this seems to  be my only way for a solution now. It makes sense given the memory constraints. Thanks, I will follow this in my code now.

Comment: @YashaswiniPrathivadi Glad to have been of help! Feel free to [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you feel it was useful to you. :-)