# Weird MemoryError in Python

Tags: python, exception, out-of-memory, python-2.6

I apologize for not being able to specify the problem any further but that's because I don't understand what is going wrong here. The error is caused by line 75 but he has all the values of the variables I call. I'm obviously missing something here, I hope someone can tell me what.

What I am trying to do is adding a string to a variable, for every part of a list.

```
<type 'exceptions.MemoryError'> Python 2.6.4: /opt/users/ipg/s/p/ipg.*********/python/python
Sat May 10 19:42:39 2014
A problem occurred in a Python script. Here is the sequence of function calls leading up to the error, in the order they occurred.

       73                                 """ % (description[field_count].value)
       74             for item in upload_field:
       75                 article_content += '<img src="http://www.*****.com/images/%s/%s">' % (link_title, item.filename)
       76             field_count = field_count + 1 
       77     elif isinstance(description, basestring):
___

    article_content undefined, link_title = 'sssfzxs', item = FieldStorage('upload_image1', '857143_7542303279...\x94\x01\xa3\x89\x82\xcc0\xc9n\xea/\x87\xff\xd9'), item.filename = '857143_754230327924155_1256712041_o.jpg'
    <type 'exceptions.MemoryError'>: 
          args = () 
          message = ''
```

Comment: Building strings with the `+=` operator is very memory inefficient. Presumably you're building such a large string that you run out of available memory. There's not really enough information here to say more, though.

Comment: @Wooble This would normally add this only 3 times to an empty string so normally it shouldn't run out of memory any time soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MemoryError` is being raised in an out of memory situations, as per the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.MemoryError).

Is there any chance your code is looping there indefinitely?

Or you may actually be hitting the memory limit on a 32-bit version of Python just because of concatenating too much data, a similar situation as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441947/why-python-memory-error-with-list-append-lots-of-ram-left). In that case, you might be able to optimize the concatenation or use a 64-bit version of Python to get you through.

Comment: I don't think I would be hitting the memory limit. The amount of data that is being transferred is very low.

Comment: Well, the memory gets filled up by something there in that process. You may put in some basic counters and logging or try to profile the memory usage with [Heapy](http://guppy-pe.sourceforge.net/#Heapy) to find the culprit.

Comment: My loop was loop was looping indefinitely indeed, it took me a wile to notice why.