# Memory error in Python while parsing a 300 MB file

Tags: python, parsing, memory

I'm parsing an xml file (291 MB) in python 3.5 with

```
import xmltodict, json

with open('Wikipedia-20160404094133.xml', encoding='utf-8') as xml_file:
    dic_xml = xmltodict.parse(xml_file.read(), encoding='utf-8', xml_attribs=True)
```

but I get the error:

```
dic_xml = xmltodict.parse(xml_file.read(), encoding='utf-8', xml_attribs=True)
MemoryError
```

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Python \`Memory Error\` with list \`append()\` lots of RAM left](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441947/why-python-memory-error-with-list-append-lots-of-ram-left)

Comment: On any relatively modern system I wouldn't expect that to cause a memory error - are you running on a shared server or cloud with limited RAM?

Comment: You need to provide more information about the system you are running on and your python installation.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [this](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict#streaming-mode).

> *"xmltodict is very fast (Expat-based) and has a streaming mode with a small memory footprint, suitable for big XML dumps like Discogs or
>   **Wikipedia**"*

Essentially, you need to read the file in chunks and xmltodict's "streaming mode" seems to be built for this.