# Python: NLTK is giving MemoryError on computing synsets using WordNet

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet

I am trying to run this code, where I calculate synsets of two words and compute a similarity between those two words. The Python code is giving a MemoryError as shown below:

**Code:**

```
def wordSim(word1,word2):
    maxscore = 0.0
    word1_synsets = word1[1]
    word2_synsets = word2[1]
    for k,j in list(product(*[word1_synsets,word2_synsets])):
        score = k.wup_similarity(j) # Wu-Palmer Similarity
        maxscore = score if maxscore < score else maxscore
    if maxscore >= 0.85:
        return True

def genSynsets(wordList):
    synsetList = map(lambda x: [x,wn.synsets(x.decode('utf-8'))],wordList)
    return synsetList
```

**Error Message:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/global/python/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/corpus/util.py", line 99, in __getattr__
    self.__load()
  File "/global/python/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/corpus/util.py", line 67, in __load
    corpus = self.__reader_cls(root, *self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/global/python/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/wordnet.py", line 1045, in __init__
    self._load_lemma_pos_offset_map()
  File "/global/python/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/wordnet.py", line 1137, in _load_lemma_pos_offset_map
    self._lemma_pos_offset_map[lemma][pos] = synset_offsets
MemoryError
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.MemoryError):

> exception MemoryError: Raised when an operation runs out of memory...

If you think you still have a bunch of free RAM, then it is likely you are running 32-bit Python and have hit the 2 or 3GB limit that that imposes. Use 64-bit Python if possible. See [Why Python `Memory Error` with list `append()` lots of RAM left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441947/why-python-memory-error-with-list-append-lots-of-ram-left).